# Is it a good practice to write several times ng-cloak for several angular expression to avoid being shown on page load?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model1">{{model1}}
```

On page load `{{model1}}` is visible. To avoid that I can make use of `ng-cloak`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model1" ng-cloak>{{model1}}
```

**CSS**

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

But it didnt seem to work for me. I can still see {{model1}} on page load.What is the issue??The same thing when I use for `<div>`, `<li>` tag it's working fine.

My another question is suppose we have 100's of expression like this `{{expression}}`, so is it a good practice to use `ng-cloak` every where. Is there any alternative way not to write `ng-cloak` every where to avoid expression being shown on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input>` does not take content, i.e. the `{{model1}}` is not *inside* the input, so the rule does not apply. You will have better luck with something like (I like closing the input tags inline, i.e. `<inp[ut />` to make explicit the fact that inputs are empty):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model1" /><span ng-cloak>{{model1}}</span>
```

As for the 100s expressions: Place a single `ng-cloak` at the root of the view hierarchy. The `display: none` rule will make sure that neither it, nor any of its children will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ng-cloak` is working on `input` elements.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model1" ng-cloak>
```

As you can see above, `input` already ends here, `{{model1}}` is not part of `input` element. A workaround is wrapping the text with `span` like `<span ng-cloak>{{model1}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

> `ng-bind` evaluates value of expression with scope variable and scope that evaluated
>   value as html of that DOM element.

Instead of adding `ng-cloak` then apply `style='display: none;'` on basis of it. I would use `ng-bind` that doesn't need to show `{{}}` interpolation on HTML while DOM is compiling angular DOM.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model1" ng-cloak><span ng-bind="model1"><span>
```

This is Alternative way so that you can avoid the use of `ng-cloak`